# Does removing a struct constitute an ABI break?

Tags: c, abi

Say I have this library:

```
// lib.h
typedef struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
} MyStruct;

int func(void);
```

None of the functions use MyStruct as arguments. Is it possible to remove `MyStruct` without breaking ABI?

Comment: No. Removing `MyStruct` would constitute an API break.

Comment: @FUZxxl: But the OP's asking about A**B**I.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh yes, in this case removing `MyStruct` wouldn't break the ABI.

Comment: @Timothy_G Are you asking about **ABI** or **API**?

Comment: @user3386109 as Oliver and I have already said, I am talking about A**B**I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *ABI break* (as opposed to an *API break*) doesn't have a rigorous definition (AFAIK), but is typically taken to refer to a modification to, say, a library that causes previously-compiled code to no longer load/run correctly.

As an unused struct definition in library *source code* won't (shouldn't) affect any compiled library artifacts, there is nothing that can possibly be broken (at runtime) by its removal.